# Wrong fragment shown after return transition

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add a fragment with a shared element transition like so

```
currentFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
    currentFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
    Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.slide_right);
    transition.setDuration(context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.fragment_transition_duration));
```

and then

```
targetFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    targetFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
    targetFragment.setReturnTransition(transition);
```

The issue I'm seeing is that once I've navigated to several of these fragments in a row, if I then tap the back button - calling the default onBackPressed() - repeatedly and very quickly, the activity shows the wrong fragment as visible.  When I tap on the screen, the click events go to the correct fragment (maybe beneath the visible fragment), but I cannot see that correct fragment.

If I tap the back button more slowly, I get the correct behavior.  Has anyone ran into a scenario like this before?

Edit : this is what FragmentActivity is doing

```
    /**
 * Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity
 * as appropriate.
 */
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
        supportFinishAfterTransition();
    }
}
```

Another thing to mention is that when I remove the Return Transition I do not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer if anyone is interested.  I don't know why this works, but it seems to fix my issue.

If you have a fragment which has a return transition set on it, then in your onDestroyView() call the method setReturningTransition(null).